# Protractor change the chrome driver version to an older version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Hi my chrome version is 76.. but my protractor web driver manager uses chrome version 78. I have changed the chrome version to 76 in the config files as shown below in the webdriver-manager config &  built folder config.

{
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.53.1",
    "chromedriver": "2.27",
    "maxChromedriver": "76",
    "geckodriver": "v0.13.0",
    "iedriver": "2.53.1",
    "androidsdk": "24.4.1",
    "appium": "1.6.5"
  },

I tried running it by running webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126.
It download the driver but when you run the web-driver manager it still uses the latest version 78.
can anyone let me know how i can run on chrome driver 76 as my chrome version is 76?

Comment: Why not just update your Chrome version?

Comment: @JeffC. Organisational restrictions. They are not allowing to update to the latest version. They use g suite for all communication

Answer (score 3):

that's what you need

`node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome $VERSION`

just don't forget to swap `$VERSION` with your version of chromedriver

Comment: This helped me install the specified version of chromedriver, but didn't help me configure the webdriver-manager to use it